# How to extend security certificate validity x509 for web service

Tags: web-services, x509certificate, keystore

My current certificate for web service validity is no longer valid, It has expired. Is there any way to extend the existing certificate.? Or else I should only create new and add it to key store again. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to extend an expired certificate.  If its your own self-signed certificate.  I would generate a new certificate and add to keystore as you suggested.